# How main.jsp locates the correct header.jsp when they are not in the same directory?

Tags: jsp, aem

I am trying to figure out how the files are included in CQ5 page component and I am a little confused about how jsp files are included.

The following are based on the out-of-box geometrixx-outdoors demo site.

in /apps/geometrixx-outdoors/components/page_sidebar/main.jsp, header.jsp is included like this:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <cq:include script="header.jsp"/>
</div>
```

But header.jsp is not in the same folder as main.jsp. Actually it is hosted at
/apps/geometrixx-outdoors/components/page/header.jsp

So I am wondering how the page knows where to find the correct header file in this case.

Looking forward to your reply.

Thanks,
Donald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ResourceTypes can be extension of others. In this case, when a script is not found in the current resource type, the resourceSuperType is checked.

if you look at `/apps/geometrixx-outdoors/components/page_sidebar` you'll see a resourceSuperType property pointing to `geometrixx-outdoors/components/page`. When `header.jsp` is not found on page_sidebar, it is looked inside page. If it wasnt found there, `foundation/components/page` would be next since it is the resourceSuperType of the geometrixx page.

Comment: Thanks Santiagozky. Your answer cannot be more specific:)